# Are Drupal webforms built using HTML?

Tags: html, drupal, webforms, drupal-webform

I want to know what kind of code is behind Drupal webforms. Is it all HTML with the input tag?

Other than Drupal, what is mostly used to build webforms?

Answer (score 1):

This should get you started
https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/webform
https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/webform/webform-features

The webforms are rendered as HTML, but are stored as Drupal entities in MySQL. The submissions from the HTML are also stored in MySQL based on the schema. I can't see any public documentation around what the specific schema is for webforms, but if you want to know the place to ask would be here
https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/webform?text=&status=All&priorities=All&categories=4&version=any_8.x-&component=All